# SmsManager sendTextMessage Not Working

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

***SmsManager sendTextMessage not working in some conditions.***

I created an android application which uses SmsManager to send message and it was working fine all the time on emulator and real devices. However recently I received few complaints from my user saying that my app could not send SMS on their devices. I pretty sure all permissions are granted and no crash and error in Crashlytics report.

I tried simulate this issue on Android Emulator and I realized that when i change cellular network type to "GSM" and change it back to "Full" several times it might cause the SmsManager sendTextMessage not working. I also added sent and delivered pending intents but none of it return error code to me. It totally no response after calling sendTextMessage method.

Please help if you have any solution about this.

**Notes:**

1. Very sure all permission are granted (READ_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS, SEND_SMS, READ_PHONE_STATE...)
2. No crash and error code from pending intent after calling sendTextMessage method.
3. Message is less than 10 characters.

---

```
public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0, new Intent(
            SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0, new Intent(
            DELIVERED), 0);

    BroadcastReceiver sendSMS = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Broadcast_SMSReceiver.mSMSReceiver.receivedSMS(true);
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Generic failure",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No service",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Null PDU",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Radio off",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_SHORT_CODE_NOT_ALLOWED:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Premium short codes denied",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_SHORT_CODE_NEVER_ALLOWED:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Premium short codes denied",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_LIMIT_EXCEEDED:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Reached the sending queue limit",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), getResultCode(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };


    BroadcastReceiver deliverSMS = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "SMS delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "SMS not delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    getActivity().registerReceiver(sendSMS, new IntentFilter(SENT));
    getActivity().registerReceiver(deliverSMS, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
    try {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, "test", sentPI, deliveredPI);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                "SMS failed, please try again later ! ",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    Broadcast_SMSReceiver.mSMSReceiver.receivedSMS(true);
}
```

Comment: same is the case with me. it is working quite well on all devices in spite of some devices on which it throws generic failure error. have you figured it out ?

Comment: I have a similar problem. Have you sorted out since?

Comment: i have too on some devices only have you sorted out ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem could be with the message that the user wanted to send was more than 160 characters.

It looks like, that if you call `SmsManager::sendTextMessage(...)` with a message that is longer than allowed, the call silently fails. No Exception is thrown, and the sentPI intent is not executed either.